# Why can't (Set -> Set) have type Set?

Tags: types, lambda-calculus, agda

In Agda, the type of a `forall` is determined in such a way that the following all have type `Set1` (where `Set1` is the type of `Set` and `A` has type `Set`):

```
Set → A
A → Set
Set → Set
```

However, the following has type `Set`:

```
A → A
```

I understand that if `Set` had type `Set`, there would be contradictions, but I'm failing to see how, if any of the three terms above had type `Set`, we would have contradictions. Can those be used to prove False? Can they be used to show that `Set : Set`?

Comment: I suppose this is more math than programming. I take it this should have been posted there instead?

Comment: Yep. mathematics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wait, why is this off-topic? This is a fairly common question for Agda or Coq, which although they are often used as proof assistants, are perfectly valid programming languages. His syntax even mirrors Agda, and the post has an Agda tag. It seems rather draconian to close the question as not programming when a tag lists a programming language and it's a valid question in that language.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question about a type in a *programming language* that has a perfectly legitimate and well defined answer. How is it an off topic post?

Comment: "Is this Math or programming?" "Yes."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is clear that `Set : Set` would cause a contradiction, such as [Russell's paradox](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/g53cfr/l20.html/l20.html).

Now consider `() -> Set` where `()` is a [unit type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type). This is clearly isomorphic to `Set`. So if `() -> Set : Set` then also `Set : Set`. In fact, if for any inhabited `A` we had `A -> Set : Set` then we could wrap `Set` into `A -> Set` using a constant function:

```
wrap1 : {A : Set} -> Set -> (A -> Set)
wrap1 v = \_ -> v
```

and get the value whenever needed as

```
unwrap1 : {A : Set}(anyInhabitant : A) -> (A -> Set) -> Set
unwrap1 anyInhabitant f = f anyInhabitant
```

So we could reconstruct Russell's paradox just as if we had `Set : Set`.

---

The same applies for `Set -> Set`, we could wrap `Set` into `Set -> Set`:

```
data Void : Set where

unwrap2 : (Set -> Set) -> Set
unwrap2 f = f Void

wrap2 : Set -> (Set -> Set)
wrap2 v = \_ -> v
```

Here we could use any type of `Set` instead of `Void`.

---

I'm not sure how to do something similar with `Set -> A`, but intuitively this seems to be even more problematic type than the other ones, maybe someone else will know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes sense now. I'm actually pretty sure that `Set -> A : Set` isn't problematic; they just chose to give it a type of `Set1` because it makes more sense. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @BrandonPickering I'm not so sure. Intuitively, `Set -> Bool` is a powerset of `Set` so it is "even larger" than `Set`. So if `Set -> A : Set` for `A` with at least 2 inhabitants then it seems reasonable that also `Set : Set`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: Allowing `Set -> A` to be in `Set` seems like it would invite [Curry's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%27s_Paradox) instead, which is so devious that GHC can be tricked into attempting to inline its entire (infinitely recursive) proof, as [you've discovered yourself](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/crash-your-favorite-compiler/7198#7198).

Comment: @C.A.McCann I tried that, but so far no success. It's a bit different situation - in Curry's Paradox one wraps the datatype into itself, while here one wraps `Set` into the datatype.

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to understand this is to consider what these things are like as set-theoretic sets, as opposed to as Agda `Set`. suppose you have `A = {a,b,c}`. An example of a function `f : A → A` is a set of pairs, let's say `f = { (a,a) , (b,b) , (c,c) }` that satisfies some properties that don't matter for this discussion. That is to say, `f`'s elements are the same sort of thing that `A`'s elements are -- they're just values, or pairs of values, nothing too "big".

Now consider the a function `F : A → Set`. It too is a set of pairs, but its pairs look different: `F = { (a,A) , (b,Nat) , (c,Bool) }` lets say. The first element of each pair is just an element of `A`, so it's pretty simple, but the *second* element of each pair is a *`Set`*! That is, the second element is itself a "big" sort of thing. So `A → Set` couldn't possibly be set, because if it were, then we should be able to have some `G : A → Set` that looks like `G = { (a,G) , ... }`. As soon as we can have this, we can get Russell's paradox. So we say `A → Set : Set1` instead.

This also addresses the issue of whether or not `Set → A` should also be in `Set1` instead of `Set`, because the functions in `Set → A` are just like the functions in `A → Set`, except that the `A`s are on the right, and the `Set`s are on the left, of the pairs.